Raspberry Pi 5 corrupting external SSD data
Setup
I have a Raspberry Pi 5 8GB, with the official active cooler, powered by the official 5A power supply. It's running Ubuntu 24.04 64-bit. I have quite a few devices connected to it: a 2.5 Gbps USB-C dongle, an external USB SSD (Crucial X6 2TB) and a powered USB hub with a bunch of microcontroller evaluation boards connected to it. The first two are connected to the USB 3.0 ports and the powered hub to an USB 2.0 port.
The issue
The SSD will be used for backing up my computers using BorgBackup, and it's formatted with ZFS. Unfortunately, every time I try to make a backup and check it afterwards, I get a bunch of random failures. These are confirmed by a ZFS scrub:
  pool: backup
 state: ONLINE
status: One or more devices has experienced an error resulting in data
    corruption.  Applications may be affected.
action: Restore the file in question if possible.  Otherwise restore the
    entire pool from backup.
   see: https://openzfs.github.io/openzfs-docs/msg/ZFS-8000-8A
  scan: scrub repaired 0B in 00:21:08 with 33 errors on Tue Jul 23 14:18:17 2024
config:

    NAME        STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
    backup      ONLINE       0     0     0
      sda       ONLINE       0     0    66

errors: Permanent errors have been detected in the following files:

        /backup/.../data/0/135
        (many similar errors)

Possible causes
Here are the usual suspects I can imagine:

Malfunctioning SSD
Bad USB cable
Power issues
Driver/hardware issues
Software issues (Borg and/or ZFS)

SSD and USB cable: very unlikely
I believe I can rule out the first two because, after noticing the errors on the Pi, I moved the SSD, with the same cable, to a PC, formatted the SSD with ZFS again, and backed up two different computers to it. Both have survived Borg checks and a ZFS scrub without any errors -- whereas with the Pi, I get errors every single time, both with Borg checks and ZFS scrubbing.
Power: possible but unlikely
Power issues seem to be the root cause behind many similar errors. While I can't 100% rule it out, I do note that vcgencmd get_throttled reported throttled=0x0 every time I tried it. According to the documentation, the Pi 5 provides 1.6 A of current to USB peripherals if using a 5A power supply (recall I'm using the official 5A power supply). This is the abridged output of lsusb -v:
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0634:5602 Micron Technology, Inc. CT2000X6SSD9
Device Descriptor:
  ...
  Configuration Descriptor:
    ...
    bmAttributes         0x80
      (Bus Powered)
    MaxPower              896mA
Bus XXX Device XXX: ID 0bda:8156 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. USB 10/100/1G/2.5G LAN
Device Descriptor:
  ...
  Configuration Descriptor:
    ...
    bmAttributes         0xa0
      (Bus Powered)
      Remote Wakeup
    MaxPower              256mA

Adding up the current used by the 2.5 Gbps Ethernet dongle and the SSD, that's about 1.15 A. The powered USB hub should draw negligible if any current, so I should be well within limits. The only uncertainty is about the power consumption of the fan since it is shared with USB. Adding up the fact that vcgencmd get_throttled is not reporting an undervoltage, I would say power should not be the prime suspect
Driver/hardware issues: possible
Reports abound of data corruption issues with the Raspberry Pi 4 and 5 using USB 3.0 SSDs. The suggested solution is to add quirks to the boot arguments. I've done that and confirmed via dmesg that usb-storage is being used for the SSD. I still get data corruption, exactly like before.
Software issues: unlikely
While I can't rule out software issues either, I note that on my PC, I am running the same Ubuntu version, using the same SSD and USB cable with the same filesystem (ZFS) and the same software (BorgBackup), and on the PC the backups work perfectly. Of course given the use of a completely different architecture (x86-64 vs. AArch64) there may be portability issues, but this is just a wild conjecture wholly unsupported by any kind of actual evidence. All in all I'd suspect driver/hardware or power before software issues.
Conclusion and question
Given all my investigations above, I'm inclined to pin it on driver/hardware issues.
My question is: other than adding quirks, are there other suggestions of workarounds for the known data corruption issues using USB3.0 SSDs?

Reports abound of data corruption issues with the Raspberry Pi 4 and 5 using USB 3.0 SSDs. really? I have three raspberry pi 4's using SSD as the boot/main drive, been running that way since the Pi 4 came up, and I've never had a single bit lost

I understand the quirks are only necessary for certain controller chips. I imagine your SSDs don't use these particular chips.

the SSD's area all different. The quality of the USB->SSD cable is what matters
